# Docker: Mount directory from one container to a specific path in another

Tags: docker

When we use "-v" argument in "docker run" command, we can specify {src path from host}:{path in container}, e.g

```
docker run -v /var/volumns/v1:/var/docker/v1ref ...
```

But, how about mounting a data-only container?

```
docker run --volumes-from data-only-container:<here is mode, ro or rw>
```

How I can achieve the same when using "-v"? Can I mount it to a specific folder?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48186109/201725. There are ways, if somewhat hacky, to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that the direct answer to your question is: no, you can't. volumes-from import the volumes exactly as they are defined in the other container.

Since docker 1.9 volume containers are being replaced with named volumes as the recommended practice. With named volumes you can mount it wherever you want :

```
docker volume create --name data
docker run -v data:/var/docker/v1ref ...
```

Regards

Comment: You can fill the container initially from a container, but you can't keep it synchronized, plus it takes up additional space. But there are some ways to do it, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/48186109/201725